# How to retrieve current workers count for job in GCP dataflow using API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-apis-explorer

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to get current workers count for active job that is running in GCP Dataflow?

I wasn't able to do it using provided by google [API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/).

One thing that I was able to get is `CurrentVcpuCount` but it is not what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe this information is returned by `projects.locations.jobs.get` under `Job.WorkerPool.numWorkers`. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#workerpool

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, thank you for the answer, as per this documentation, `numWorkers` is the Number of Google Compute Engine workers in this pool **needed to** execute the job, so as far as I understood it is a predefined value. But what I need is the **current** amount of workers per job in realtime.

Comment: Moreover, I forgot to mention that `projects.locations.jobs.get` returns a response that doesn't contain `com.google.api.services.dataflow.model.Environment#workerPools` field...

Comment: I believe if you set :
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/JobView
To JOB_VIEW_ALL you should get back the machine type.
Can you use that along with the CurrentVcpuCount for what you need?

Comment: Hi @RezaRokni, thank you for the hint with JOB_VIEW_ALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current number of workers in a Dataflow job are displayed in the message logs, under `autoscaling`. For example, I did a quick job as example and I got the following message, when displaying the job logs in my Cloud Shell:

```
INFO:root:2019-01-28T16:42:33.173Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 0 based on the rate of progress in the currently running step(s).
INFO:root:2019-01-28T16:43:02.166Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Autoscaling: Raised the number of workers to 1 based on the rate of progress in the currently running step(s).
INFO:root:2019-01-28T16:43:05.385Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Workers have started successfully.
INFO:root:2019-01-28T16:43:05.433Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Workers have started successfully.
```

Now, you can query these messages by using the [`projects.jobs.messages.list`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs.messages/list) method, in the Data flow API, and setting the `minimumImportance` parameter to be `JOB_MESSAGE_BASIC`.

You will get a response similar to the following:

```
...
"autoscalingEvents": [
    {...} //other events
    {

      "currentNumWorkers": "1",
      "eventType": "CURRENT_NUM_WORKERS_CHANGED",
      "description": {
          "messageText": "(fcfef6769cff802b): Worker pool started.",
          "messageKey": "POOL_STARTUP_COMPLETED"
      },
      "time": "2019-01-28T16:43:02.130129051Z",
      "workerPool": "Regular"
    },
```

To extend this you could create a python script to parse the response, and only get the parameter `currentNumWorkers` from the last element in the list `autoscalingEvents`, to know what is the last (hence the current) number of workers in the Job.

Note that if this parameter is not present, it means that the number of workers is zero.

**Edit**:

I did a quick python script that retrieves the current number of workers, from the message logs, using the API I mentioned above:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery


credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename='PATH-TO-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-KEY/key.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
            'dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials)




project_id="MY-PROJECT-ID"
job_id="DATAFLOW-JOB-ID"

messages=service.projects().jobs().messages().list(
            projectId=project_id,
            jobId=job_id
        ).execute()

try:
    print("Current number of workers is "+messages['autoscalingEvents'][-1]['currentNumWorkers'])
except:
    print("Current number of workers is 0")
```

A couple of notes:

- The scopes are the permissions needed on the service account key you are referencing (in the `from_service_account_file` function), in order to do the call to the API. This line is needed to authenticate to the API. You can use any one of [this list](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs.messages/list#authorization-scopes), to make it easy on my side, I just used a service account key with `project/owner` permissions.
- If you want to read more about the Python API Client Libraries, check [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started), and [this samples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client).

Answer (score -2):

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-5513132861824326",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>
```